# how does lucene build VSM?

Tags: lucene, indexing, data-mining, similarity, tf-idf

I understand the concept of VSM, TFIDF and cosine similarity, however, I am still confused about how lucene build VSM and calculate similarity for each query after reading lucene website.

As I understood, VSM is a matrix where the values of TFIDF of each term are filled. When i tried building VSM from a set of documents, it took a long time with this tool http://sourceforge.net/projects/wvtool/
This is not really related to the coding, because intuitively building a VSM matrix of large data is time consuming, but that seems not the case for lucene.

In additon, with a VSM prebuilt, finding most similar document which basically is the calculation of similarity between two documents or a query vs document often time consuming (assume millions of documents, because one has to compute similarity to everyone else), but lucene seems does it really fast. I guess that's also related to how it builds VSM internally. If possible, can someone also explain this ?

so please help me to understand two point here: 
1. how lucene builds VSM so fast which can be used for calculating similarity.
2. how come lucene similarity calculation amoung millions of documents is so fast.

I'd appreciate it if an real example is given.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As I understood, VSM is a matrix where the values of TFIDF of each term are filled.

This is more properly called a **term-document matrix**. The VSM is more of a conceptual framework from which this matrix, and the notion of cosine similarity arise.

Lucene stores term frequencies and document frequencies that can be used to get tf-idf weights for document and query terms. It uses those to compute a variant of cosine similarity outlined [here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html). So, the rows of the term-document matrix are represented in the index, which is a hash table mapping terms to (document, tf) pairs plus a separate table mapping terms to their df value.

> one has to compute similarity to everyone else

That's not true. If you review the textbook definition of cosine similarity, you'll find that it's the sum of products of corresponding term weights in a query and a document, normalized. Terms that occur in the document but not the query, or vice versa, have no effect on the similarity. It follows that, to compute cosine similarity, you only need to consider those documents that have some term in common with the query. That's how Lucene gets its speed: it does a hash table lookup for the query terms and computes similarities only to the documents that have non-zero intersection with the query's bag of words.

Comment: even though the VSM is implicit in lucene, does it still build a temporary VSM in order to compare similarity between one to all documents? my understanding is that such calculation is time consuming

Comment: @ikel If by "VSM" you mean a term-document matrix, then no. Why would it?

Comment: sow how exactly does lucene build implicit VSM then? (by VSM i mean term-document matrix with TFIDF values)

Comment: Given a query, it looks up which documents contain the query terms. It can then compute tf-idf values for those terms only and compute cosine similarity; all other terms are irrelevant since they don't contribute to similarity at all.

Comment: @ikel Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @larsmans Is Lucene able to pre compute a similarity matrix across all documents within the corpus?  I'm interested in precomputing a large set of documents to create visualizations of pre-weighted similarity rather than by search match similarity.  Currently I'm doing this using https://github.com/opennorth/tf-idf-similarity, but it is quite slow; takes more than a day to process across a relatively small dataset.